# The caller was not authenticated by the service wsDualHttpBinding

Tags: c#, wcf

I have searched and tried to apply the solution given on the other posts, but i cant solve my problem yet.

I have to use wsDualHttpBinding for duplex connection.
When I try to run my client on the same machine with the WCF server, it can run perfectly, but when i move the client to other machine on the same domain, it return an error "The caller was not authenticated by the service"

here is the app.config on my client

```
<wsDualHttpBinding>
  <binding name="duplexendpoint" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
      receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
      transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
  <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
      maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
  <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" />
  <security mode="Message">
      <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
  </security>

  </binding>
</wsDualHttpBinding>
```

then i tried to give the credential via the code :

```
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "serverusername";
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "serverpassword";
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = "serverdomain";
```

and it give an error "Client is unable to finish  the security negotiation within the configured timeout"

is there any way to solve my problem? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

oke I have found the solution for my problem, i have to turn off the firewall from the client machine.